# WCF Service won't work under HTTPS / SSL

Tags: wcf, silverlight, iis, ssl, https

I have a WCF service that I'm using in my Silverlight project. I've followed pretty much any information on how to set up https and ssl for WCF services. The service can be called perfectly fine if SSL in not required but I noticed while examining the communications with fiddler that the WCF service was still in http protocol. Further more if I enable SSL the WCF service cant be browsed in a browser (right clicking in VS2010 -> selecting browse) .

My suspicion is that the service is still being called on some internal method with the http protocol.

Any suggestions to how to fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="">
            <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>

      <bindings>

        <customBinding>
          <binding name="AuthService.customBinding" >
            <binaryMessageEncoding />
            <httpsTransport />
          </binding>
        </customBinding>
      </bindings>
      <services>
          <service name="AuthService">
              <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="AuthService.customBinding" contract="AuthService" />
              <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          </service>

      </services>

  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Thanks

Comment: Any specific reason on why you are using a custom binding. Also your service name attribute and contract attribute needs to be fully qualified

Comment: Rajesh, fully qualifying the names caused it to work properly. I'm pretty green when it comes to server side coding and web.config files.
Should I just be using a basichttpbinding or maybe a wshttpbinding. Maybe ill go read up on the WCF configurations Schema.

Thanks Rajesh, I would like to mark your comment as the answer.

Comment: Do you mean it works without any problem now or it still doesnt work when you try over https

Comment: It works with SSL set to required and i checked fiddler and its using the https protocol. :)

Comment: I would post the same as an answer and it would be great if you could mark it as an answer

Comment: ((unrelated to this question)) @DrStereo, I refused your [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/319907) b/c it should be an answer on its own. Please copy your text from their and post it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any specific reason on why you are using a custom binding. Also your service name attribute and contract attribute needs to be fully qualified.

You can use simple basicHttpBinding if you want your WCF service to be compliant with basic profile 1.1 which allows non .NET clients to access as well.

Comment: name attribute and contract attribute needs to be fully qualified XD